# Why did the button in JavaFX application turn white?

Tags: java, button, javafx, border

I want border of a button to turn black when you click on the button. I use setStyle () to do this, but for some reason the button turns white.

And in Scenebuilder is all right. What can be the cause of this phenomenon and how can it be corrected?

[image: Layout in the Scenebuilder]

[image: Application state afler click on the Button]

```
view.getAddActivityButton().setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
    Button act = view.getAddActivityButton();
    Button search = view.getAddSearchActivityButton();
                    view.getToolbarActivityPanel().getItems().remove(view.getAddActivityButton());
                    view.getToolbarActivityPanel().getItems().remove(view.getAddSearchActivityButton());

    TextField nameOfActivityTextField = new TextField();
                     view.getToolbarActivityPanel().getItems().add(0,newActivityHBox);
    newActivityHBox.getChildren().add(0, act);
    newActivityHBox.setMargin(act,new Insets(0));
    act.setStyle("-fx-border-color: black;");
    nameOfActivityTextField.setMaxHeight(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    newActivityHBox.getChildren().add(1,nameOfActivityTextField);
    newActivityHBox.getChildren().add(2, search);
/*...**/

 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you call setStyle( "some text" ) is replaced with the whole style, not just the specified option. Accordingly, there are several ways to bypass:

1) `act.setStyle("-fx-border-color: black;-fx-background-color: black");`

2)

```
act.getStyleClass().add( "blackButton" );
//act.setId( "blackButton" );
.blackButton {
/*#blackButton {*/
    -fx-background-color: black;
    -fx-border-color: white;
}
act.setStyle( "-fx-border-color: black;" );
```

3)

```
act.getStyleClass().add( "blackButton" );
.blackButton {
    -fx-background-color: black;
    -fx-border-color: white;
}
#blackBorder {
    -fx-border-color: black;
}
act.setId( "blackBorder" );
```